# October CMS | How to turn off flash messages or alerts

Tags: octobercms

On my application I need to throw some erros, so following the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log#ajax-exception) I can throw some errors with custom messages and/or render some partial by using the following code:

```
throw new AjaxException([
     '#error_box' => Lang::get('xxx.xxxx::lang.frontend.error_ajax_und')
]);
```

The problem is that I see flash messages with "Default text" and I don't know how to turn it off...

[image]

debug mode is **disabled**

october build: 419

Comment: `$(window).on('ajaxErrorMessage', ..` don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could hook into the `ajaxSetup` event to disable flash error handling: http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api#global-events-examples

Something along the lines of:

```
$(document).on('ajaxSetup', function(event, context) {
    // Disable AJAX handling of Flash messages on all AJAX requests
    context.options.flash = false
})
```

or

```
$(document).on('ajaxSetup', function(event, context) {
    // Handle Error Messages with a custom handler
    context.options.handleErrorMessage = function(message) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // Handle Flash Messages with a custom handler
    context.options.handleFlashMessage = function(message, type) {
        // do stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: `context.options.flash = false` gives no results, but `context.options.handleErrorMessage = function(message)` works! thank you!